# Async and await: multiple await expressions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having a little difficulty understanding how use async and await work.

I understand that when an async method hits an await expression, the method returns immediately and at some point in the future the await expression returns and the method continues to execute.

What I don't understand, then, is what happens when an async method contains more than one await expression? When execution hits the second await expression, since the method has already returned after the first await expression was hit, what happens to execution around the second await expression?

I am currently reading two books on async and await but my dark mind has been illuminated by neither!

Answer (score 5):

> I understand that when an async method hits an await expression, the method returns immediately and at some point in the future the await expression returns and the method continues to execute.

Yes, *if* the awaitable hasn't already completed.

> When execution hits the second await expression, since the method has already returned after the first await expression was hit, what happens to execution around the second await expression?

It returns control to whatever executed the continuation, which will depend on the context. In a WinForms app in the UI thread, it would just be the event loop. In a thread pool thread, it would just be the thread pool scheduler.

Chances are whatever calls the continuation really doesn't care about it at all - it's just "something to execute in a context". It's likely to go ahead and just execute whatever it needs to do next (or wait until there's more work).

The important point is that by now the *first* caller has the appropriate `Task` or `Task<T>` so that they can tell when the whole async method has completed.

Comment: Isn't the answer quite simply : the same as with the first await. ie the method will return immediately at the second point too, unless already completed, and at a point in the future the second await expression returns and the method continues to execute yet again. And this happens for all the awaits that might occur sequentially in the method.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: The point is that the OP is confused (I believe) about what the second caller *is* that the method is returning to.

Comment: So while the first awaitable is executing, the code returns to complete the caller's code? Whereas during the second awaitable, control returns to the UI thread or the thread pool scheduler?

Comment: @serlingpa: Pretty much, yes. (I don't think of it as "while an awaitable is executing" though - it's just that the awaitable hasn't completed yet. For things like Task.Delay, it's not actually doing anything - it just doesn't complete until after the delay.)

Answer (score 2):

It might help to recall that for each await the compiler encounters, it will rewrite the rest of the method as a continuation. So 2 awaits would result in 2 (nested) continuations, roughly equivalent (though overly simplified) to:

```
FirstAsyncThing().ContinueWith(x => {
    SecondAsyncThing().ContinueWith(y => {
        // etc.
    });
});
```

So just as the first await immediately returns control to the method's caller, the second returns control to first *continuation*'s caller, which is the first part of the original method.